# Where is the right version of MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js for MVC 2 beta 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

`MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js` is used by ASP.NET MVC 2 for client side validation.

Having problems with this file just not working properly and wondering if I have the wrong version.

The version I am using came from the source for futures.

```
 MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js
 5,626 bytes
 11/17/09 10:43:12am
```

There are two reasons i think i have the wrong version :

1) I actually have to call this code to get the validation routine working at all. This is because the default client validation function now embedded into `FormContext.cs` is `Sys.Mvc.FormValidation.enableClientValidation` .

```
 ViewContext.FormContext.ClientValidationFunction = "EnableClientValidation";
```

2) There is some code from jquery.validate.js which does the followin :

```
  this.settings.errorPlacement
    ? this.settings.errorPlacement(label, $(element) )
    : label.insertAfter(element);
```

This calls into this function in `MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js` :

```
 errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        var messageSpan = fieldToMessageMappings[element.attr("name")];
        $(messageSpan).empty();
        $(messageSpan).removeClass("field-validation-valid");
        $(messageSpan).addClass("field-validation-error");
        error.removeClass("input-validation-error");
        error.attr("_for_validation_message", messageSpan);
        error.appendTo(messageSpan);
    },
```

The problem is that element has been wrapped by `jQuery.validate` with the jQuery `$(element)` expression.

Therefore `element.attr("name")` is undefined, but `element[0].attr("name")` is valid.

I've taken `MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js` from the futures download on [Microsoft's site](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=36054).
`

I cant find any other `MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation` version - but I'm sure there must be one. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please clarify which preview of ASP.NET MVC 2 you are using? There is no "Beta 2" but there is a Preview 2 as well as a Beta and an RC. ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2 is also included in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2. Yes, it's confusing!

Comment: OK well this question is somewhat out of date now that there is an RC. please see my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934803/how-do-i-use-microsoftmvcvalidation-js-without-having-to-include-microsoftajax-js which should help

Comment: oh and I meant Preview 2 (well RC wasnt out when i wrote this question anyway)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Dec 17, 2009 the latest version of `MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js` is available in the [futures download project](http://code.google.com/p/arscloud/source/browse/trunk/MvcFutures/MvcFutures/MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js?r=7).

Be careful to include `MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js` and [NOT the similarly named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934803/how-do-i-use-microsoftmvcvalidation-js-without-having-to-include-microsoftajax-js) `MicrosoftMvcValidation.js`.

Comment: Is this code still relevant now vs2010 has shipped as futures link is dead, where will I find this js file?

Comment: You can find it in either the "ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM Source Code" or in the "ASP.NET MVC 2 Future", both avalable at: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742

Comment: @tigermain Even though VS 2010 has shipped (for awhile at the time of this writing), what's indicated here still seems to be the right place to find MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js. If I create a new project in VS for an MVC 2 (non-futures) project or even an MVC 3 Preview 1 project this file isn't in the project by default. I'm assuming if I still MVC 2 futures and created a new project it would be there, though.