# How do I use MicrosoftMvcValidation.js without having to include MicrosoftAjax.js?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It looks like there's an issue in MVC 2 RC1 if you want to use jQuery.Validate but not the main Microsoft AJAX - which is 25kb even when gzipped.

According to Phil Haack you're supposed to be able to [just include these scripts](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx):

```
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Unfortunately in some reorganization they did between Beta and RC - you also now need to include `MicrosoftAjax.js` which defines the `Type` prototype functions that are used by `MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js` (the first line is `Type.registerNamespace('Sys.Mvc');` which is defined in `MicrosoftAjax.js`)

Has anyone already extracted out the necessary code from `MicrosoftAjax.js` that is needed?
I'll have to do it sooner or later but if anyone has already done it that would help a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Aha!

Looks like `MicrosoftMvcValidation.js` is NOT the file needed for `jQuery.validate`.

You need to use the very similarly named `MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js`. This has no dependency on `Microsoft.Ajax.js`.

**The latest version of `MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js` is available in the [futures download project](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=37423).** It isn't included in the normal download - hence my confusion.

Comment: The futures project has moved to: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742, the script is also available in the MVC 2 Source Code download

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jumping through hoops to get this working, you might want to look into letting [Microsoft/Google serve the AJAX library for you](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/announcing-the-microsoft-ajax-cdn.aspx). This would likely give you a speed advantage. And a good chance that the library will already exist on the client's machine.

Comment: i already have too many javascript files i need. this is my limit for sure. plus its definitely kind of a bug - albeit easy to fix. plus hopefully people will find this and understand the problem sooner