# jQuery 1.7.1 Breaks Unobtrusive Validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

With VS2010's default MVC3 project template, jQuery version is 1.5.1 and it works fine to support Unobtrusive Validation.

Today I downloaded jQuery 1.7.1 to replace 1.5.1 and Unobtrusive Validation stopped working. The JS files I have in my project are:

- jquery-1.5.1.min.js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
- jquery.validate.min.js
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

I deleted all other JS files.

The only difference in my code is to choose different version of jQuery.

Anybody else experienced same issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [author's site](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), it's only verified to be working with up to jQuery 1.6.1. Though I use 1.6.4 currently with no noticeable problems, it would not surprise me if 1.7.* has breaking changes that need to be accounted for before the unobtrusive validation works with it. I haven't upgraded to 1.7.1 yet (or rather I did, and have since rolled back), because when I tried 1.7 I ran into other compatibility issues with Telerik's MVC controls.

Edit: I just noticed the link I tracked down was for the validation plugin not the unobtrusive validation plugin. Unless the most [recent](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/jQuery.Validation) [versions](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive) still has an issue with it, I can only suggest that you wait until they make the necessary adjustments before upgrading to 1.7.*

Edit: Also, I made a comment below but you may want to try the Nuget package and see if this helps resolve your problem, I have no issues with this now. http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation

Comment: Out of curiosity, which Telerik MVC controls do you use?

Comment: My problems mainly had to do with their grid and tree view controls. Specifically the client side click event had the issue. It was a confirmed bug in 1.7 and I haven't tried 1.7.1 yet to see if it has fixed the issue.

Comment: I have same problem and my custom validation functions does not work with jQuery 1.7.1, so I have reverted my version with old 1.5.1 and all my custom validation stated working.

Comment: Maybe give the Nuget packages a shot and see if they help resolve your problem, I have no issues with this now.
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the MicrosoftMvcValidation.js.  I am using jquery-1.6.2 and it seems to work fine.

You have to wait for that library to be updated before you can update the jquery version.

Take a look at this answer.

[jquery_validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878076/where-is-the-right-version-of-microsoftmvcjqueryvalidation-js-for-mvc-2-beta-2)